# Digital Wellbeing in Secure folder Android 10

Tags: applications, google-play-store, samsung, google, android-10

How can I use Digital Wellbeing in Secure folder Android 10? I am using Samsung A70.

Basically I would like to restrict usage of certain apps inside my secure folder and if possible I would like to have a launcher for secure folder like [Desert Island - A Digital Wellbeing Experiment - Apps on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digitalwellbeingexperiments.desertisland&hl=en). I am able to install it but I have  to manually activate it everytime I go inside secure folder.